# Non-Indexable and Indexable pages at same time on Screaming Frog

Tags: web-crawler, seo, google-search-console

I am developing a website on wordpress using OceanWP theme and Elementor. When scaning on Screaming Frog I have some pages that are: Indexability:Non-Indexable, Status:Moved Permanently, Indexability Status: Redirected. Some pages are Status:OK but Non-Indexable - Canonicalised.
All that pages are redirected to same URL that is correct by the way.

But at same time all that pages are Indexable and Status: Ok at same time on same scaning on Screaming Frog.

Why is this happening and can that negative impact my SEO?
I dont even know what to try. I have checked a website and everything looks good.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because, as the seo tag states: SEO QUESTIONS ARE OFF-TOPIC. Only programming-related SEO questions are acceptable on Stack Overflow. Non-programming SEO questions should be asked on Webmasters.SE at https://webmasters.stackexchange.com. Please delete your question here first.